# Run an input file using an exe file with cmd

Tags: cmd

I am using Windows 7

How can i run an input file (text file of commands) in an exe progam in CMD please.

Using other questions on the site, i have tried:

```
CMD /c ""C:/Program Files/Mplus/Mpluswin.exe" "C:/Users/jj/Desktop/mplus/test_mplus.inp""
```

which opens the input file in the program but does not run it

and this, which opens the program, but not the script

```
CMD /c "C:/Program Files/Mplus/Mpluswin.exe" < "C:/Users/jj/Desktop/mplus/test_mplus.inp"
```

Does this depend on the exe program?

Edit:

At present, the first command above launches the exe program  and  opens the text file within it (this is a file of program specific commands that will read in data, run calculations and output automatically). I can then run the commands in the exe program that has been opened (by selecting run in a menu) . But, I would like to pass the file to the exe program and it to be run automatically, ideally in the background.  I am not sure of the correct terminology to use, so sorry if my description is unclear.

Comment: Do you want to launch an exe program, with each line in a plain text file as an argument?

Comment: @foxidrive; Sorry i am unsure if each line of the file should be passed as an argument or the whole file should get passed at once. In the open exe program the whole text file would need to be passed /run at once to terminate correctly. I added a little extra description above. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is the exe program a command line application (i.e. it runs in the same CMD window), or a graphical application? If it's a graphical application, the answer is going to be application-specific, if there is even a solution at all.

Comment: @RobinGreen; it is a graphical application (a basic one). I thought it may be exe specific - thanks for the comment.

Comment: After checking the manual, there is no mention of command line options or loading scripts.  GUI programs can and do have the ability, but this one doesn't seem to have it - or it's called something else.

Comment: @foxidrive; Thanks. I also checked the manual and found this for the demo version (i have the full): http://www.statmodel.com/demo.shtml. This is what i tried (or attempted to try) above but no success

Comment: Open the cmd prompt in the mplus.exe folder and type the following to see if this does work to create the output file: `mplus myfile.imp outfile.out` and also try a very simple test case and verify that it works when opening the exe interactively first.

Comment: @foxidrive; great, thank you for your help; that works. I have to cd to the exe folder to get this to work (but it is ok to have input file in a different directory). Do you know why i would have to cd whereas passing the full filepath to the exe doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe it has support files in the location and can't otherwise find them.  Without having the app it is hard to be certain.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just noticed that you enclosed the entire term in an extra set of double quotes, and used linux forward slashes - try this batch file and also see if there is any error message on the console.

```
@echo off
cd /d "%userprofile%\Desktop\mplus"
"C:\Program Files\Mplus\Mpluswin.exe" "test_mplus.inp"
echo mplus was launched
pause
```

Comment: This opened, but didn't run the file. But your comment above solved my issue. Thanks millions for your help.